# List item permissions thru SharePoint 2010 Web Services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, permissions

Through web searches I've seen that SharePoint 2010 Web Services does **NOT** provide a web service for determining list `item` permissions (or at least, that was the case for SharePoint 2007).  Many web search results, including several here on stackoverflow, ultimately end up linking to the following article:

http://www.codefornuts.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html

Very promising indeed yet the source code link there no longer works.  So, the marked "answer" to all of these questions has become a bit of a non-answer.  I can go try to create my own custom web service but the previously provided answer would be fantastic.  Does anyone know where that source code can be found?  Does anyone know whether SharePoint 2010 has an OOTB web service to access list item permissions?